# How to say 索尼大法好 in English?

Tags: translation

I didn't know what 大法 means. I did some google search and all the answers were "Dafa".

But I didn't think it is correct. What does it mean exactly?

Comment: To maintain the humor, I suggest "Sony dafa is good." Seriously. As a parody of the original "Falun dafa is good."

Comment: It came from the declaration **法\*轮** ***大\*法*** 好: **Dharma-cakra**, ***the great dharma***, is good, people replace the first two characters with **sony**: Sony, the great dharma, is good!

Comment: The great dharma of cakra is good! The great dharma of sony is good!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

索尼 is Sony.
大法 is borrowed from Falungong's 法轮大法.

The inventor of this saying might want to gave people some ideas on how Sony's fans follow Sony's industrial design.

How about translate to Sony cult supremacy or Sony sect supremacy?

Answer (score 6):

In this sentence people treat Sony like a religion. 
So I think the best way to translate it is

"**In Sony we trust**"

Answer (score 4):

法，or 大法 is borrowed from Buddhism， in Buddhism， 法 means 轨持（dharma），truth or law that affects the whole universe。

so 索尼大法好 can be The dharma of Sony is good , or The truth of Sony is good for simplicity.

Answer (score -1):

I think the accurate translation is **Sony is the best**

Comment: "大法" means you are the fan of Sony - might be misleading. Additional explanation would be better.

Answer (score -1):

Literally, 大法 means "great magic" ，which used to be a superstitious description of "theory／technic" in ancient time.

example:

```
点金大法 点金术 alchemy
易容大法 易容术 magic disguise
```

Now 大法 is often used as a humorous yet satirising description of metaphysical entities like "art","music","emotions" 
which cannot be completely measured or assessed by science.

suggested translation:

```
Sonyism Rocks!
```

Answer (score -1):

The sentence is Sony’s fans’s sayings 
索尼 is “Sony”
大法 feel like “religious magic”
好 is good
 in fact this sentence have some jokemeaning in Chinese
[image]
if you are a Google fans you can say
谷歌大法好
my English maybe is not very well，if you can not understand please tell me